# Почему возникает ошибка cannot convert ‘char (*)[8]’ to ‘char**’ in initialization?

Tags: c++

```
char **letters = new char[8][8];
```

> `x.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:  
> x.cpp:2: error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[8]’ to ‘char**’ in initialization`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мне не изменяет память, чтобы выделить память под двумерный массив, нужно сперва инициализировать сам массив (строки массива), а затем элементы каждой строки.

```
#define ROWS 8
#define COLS 8
char **letters = new char*[ROWS];
for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++) {
    letters[i] = new char[COLS];
    for(int j=0; j<COLS; j++) {
        letters[i][j] = 'c';
        printf("%c", letters[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Результат:

```
cccccccc
cccccccc
cccccccc
cccccccc
cccccccc
cccccccc
cccccccc
cccccccc
```

Comment: Во-первых, этот ответ не является ответом на поставленный вопрос: "Почему возникает ошибка...". Во-вторых, что значит "нужно"? Кому "нужно"? Автор вопроса хочет создать массив `char [8][8]`. У вас же создается "jagged" массив, который `char [8][8]` совсем не является.

Comment: полностью согласен

Answer (score 4):

Оператор new возвращает указатель на массив `char[8]`, поэтому и инициализируемая переменная должная быть `char[8]`.

```
typedef char LETTERS[8];

LETTERS *letters = new char[8][8];
```

Answer (score 4):

Вызов `new char[8][8]` создает двумерный массив типа `char[8][8]`, и, как обычно, возвращает указатель на его первый элемент: на массив `char[8]`. То есть тип результата в данном случае - `char (*)[8]`. Тип `char (*)[8]` не имеет никакого отношения к вашему `char **`. Поэтому и возникает ошибка.

Правильно:

```
char (*letters)[8] = new char[8][8];
```